# Tensorflow shape construction

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to make a model for sentiment analysis, here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
import logging
import nltk
import re
import numpy
from keras.layers import Dense, LSTM, Input, Dropout, Embedding
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import Adam
import spacy.lang.en.stop_words
```

Here we load data:

```
logging.basicConfig(format='%(asctime)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s', level=logging.INFO)
df_pos = pd.read_csv("E:\...\positive_test.csv", sep=";",header=None)
df_pos = df_pos.dropna().drop_duplicates()
pos_count = len(df_pos)
df_neg = pd.read_csv("E:\...\negative_test.csv",sep=";", header=None)
df_neg = df_neg.dropna().drop_duplicates()
neg_count = len(df_neg)
df = df_pos.iloc[:, 3].append(df_neg.iloc[:, 3])
df = df.dropna().drop_duplicates()

patterns = "[A-Za-z0-9!#$%&'()*+,./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~—„“\"«»\-]+"
stopwords = spacy.lang.en.stop_words.STOP_WORDS
```

Lemmatisation.

```
def lemmatize(doc):
    ...cringe, it just works...

data = df.apply(lemmatize)
data = data.dropna()
data = list(data)
```

I wanted to use this model, but the problem appears both with w2v and usual embedding.

```
w2v_model = Word2Vec(
    min_count=2,
    window=2,
    vector_size=300,
    negative=10,
    alpha=0.03,
    min_alpha=0.0007,
    sample=6e-5,
    sg=1)
w2v_model.build_vocab(data)
w2v_model.train(data, total_examples=w2v_model.corpus_count, epochs=30, report_delay=1)
w2v_model.init_sims(replace=True)
w2v_model.save('my_W2V.model')
```

Definitely a model.

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(1000, 128))
# or model.add(gensim_to_keras_embedding(word2vec_model))
model.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(64))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
model.summary()

model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=Adam(0.001))
```

Making length of sentences equal:

```
maxLen = 0
for i in range(0, len(data)):
    if len(data[i]) > maxLen:
        maxLen = len(data[i])

for i in range(0, len(data)):
    while len(data[i]) < maxLen:
        data[i].append('0')

X = data
```

Here I write -3 to make sizes equal (smells for a while).

```
Y = list([1] * pos_count + [0] * (neg_count-3))
history = model.fit(X, Y, epochs=50)
```

After all I get this problem:

```
ValueError: Shapes (32, 1) and (32, 2) are incompatible
```

Why? And what do I need to make them equal? How can I get information about shapes?
`.shape` does not work though.

Comment: Hi @XEX, Changing `model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))` to `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))` and loss to `binary_crossentropy` in the compile() method will help as it is a binary classification problem. Thank you.

Comment: Hi @Tfer3 , thanks a lot. But now I get  `UNIMPLEMENTED: Cast string to float is not supported`
 and 
`Node: 'sequential/Cast'
Cast string to float is not supported
  [[{{node sequential/Cast}}]] [Op:__inference_train_function_4726]`

Google says, that maybe it is connected with my gensim model. But it seems working fine, after using `word2vec_model.wv.word_vec('word')` I see 
[ 0.01858463  0.09671034 -0.06921414  0.02191764  0.01819165 ...] array. Where might be the point?

Comment: The data in Y could be of type string, encoding it might help.